# query plan caching (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, performance

Is there a measure of time frame as to which the execution plan of inline queries will cached?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an algorithm (will find it), but *practically* it will stay there:

- while being used (Edit: See AdaTheDev's answer)
- until statistics update (also implied by index rebuild)
- until definition changes (including whitespace and case)
- SQL instance restart
- until severe memory pressure

[SQL Server 2008 article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055.aspx)

Comment: The stats update will invalidate the plan, but doesn't immediately remove it bizarrely.

Comment: yes, seen that. also ALTER PROC (get "definition has been changed or similar' error).

Answer (score 4):

As gbn said, there is an algorithm. Just to add that the length of time a plan will be cached for also relates to how valuable a plan is deemed to be and how often it is used (if it's a higher value plan, and it keeps getting used then it's value is very high so will be more likely to be held for longer than other plans)